# What is spatial resolution of TROPOMI data in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, resolution

In the description of TROPOMI NO2/HCHO data, the spatial resolution is 0.01 arc degree [see following(1)], however the Image Properties says the spatial resolution is 3.5×7.5 km² [see following(2)]. Also, I print the properties of this data and the spatial resolution is 3.5×7.5 km² [see following(3)].

My question is what the spatial resolution of TROPOMI NO2/HCHO data?

1. > [The Sentinel-5 Precursor mission instrument collects data useful for assessing air quality.](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/sentinel-5p) The TROPOMI instrument is a multispectral sensor that records reflectance of wavelengths important for measuring atmospheric concentrations of ozone, methane, formaldehyde, aerosol, carbon monoxide, nitrogen oxide, and sulphur dioxide, as well as cloud characteristics at a spatial resolution of 0.01 arc degrees.
2. > [SPATIAL_RESOLUTION](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_OFFL_L3_NO2#image-properties) STRING: Spatial resolution at nadir. For most products this is `3.5x7km2`, except for `L2__O3__PR`, which uses `28x21km2`, and `L2__CO____` and `L2__CH4___`, which both use `7x7km2`. This attribute originates from the CCI standard.
3. ```
   PRODUCT_ID:  S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20191231T011147_20191231T025317_11473_01_010302_20200101T180133  
   PRODUCT_QUALITY: NOMINAL  
   SENSOR: TROPOMI  
   SPATIAL_RESOLUTION: 7x3.5km2  
   STATUS_CTMFCT: Nominal  
   STATUS_MET_2D: Nominal
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The pixel size when running harp to produce L3 data is set to be 0.01 degrees (~ 1km), which is intentionally a bit finer than the expected data resolution of 3.5×7.5 km².